# Uso indebido de setInterval jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, setinterval

estoy usando una función que se ejecuta cada 2 minutos que detecta novedades, utilicé `setInterval`. El tema es que la primera vez, no lo hace inmediatamente.
 Cuando empece a buscar como resolverlo, algunos no recomendaban el uso de `setInterval`, porque puede que se acumulen las ejecuciones. No encuentro otra forma de buscar novedades(algo asi como push no exite nada que yo sepa). Hay alguna otra forma de solucionar esto?

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    function ActuaCampana() {             
        var Atipo=1;        
        $.ajax({
            url:'../phpAux/ProcesoCampana.php',
                type:'POST',
                data:'Tipo='+Atipo,                    
            success: function (campanazo) {  
                if (campanazo == 0){                     
                    $('.NotiCampana').html('<i id="CampanaMensajes" class="fa fa-bell-o"></i><span id="badgeCampana" class ="badge "></span>'); 
                } else {
                    $('.NotiCampana').html('<i id="CampanaMensajes" class="fa fa-bell faa-ring animated "></i><span id="badgeCampana" class ="badge ">'+campanazo+'</span>'); 
                }                    
            },
        });
    }
    setInterval(ActuaCampana,120*1000); });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si te he entendido bien quieres que se ejecute la primera vez inmediatamente. La solución es muy simple.

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    function ActuaCampana() {             
        var Atipo=1;        
        $.ajax({
            url:'../phpAux/ProcesoCampana.php',
                type:'POST',
                data:'Tipo='+Atipo,                    
            success: function (campanazo) {  
                if (campanazo == 0){                     
                    $('.NotiCampana').html('<i id="CampanaMensajes" class="fa fa-bell-o"></i><span id="badgeCampana" class ="badge "></span>'); 
                } else {
                    $('.NotiCampana').html('<i id="CampanaMensajes" class="fa fa-bell faa-ring animated "></i><span id="badgeCampana" class ="badge ">'+campanazo+'</span>'); 
                }                    
            },
        });
    }
   //Inserta esta línea aquí
    ActuaCampana()
    setInterval(ActuaCampana,120*1000); });
```

Comment: Y por otro lado la pregunta es, Esta bien usar setInterval?

Comment: Pero el codigo que agregaste, no crea un loop, antes de llegar a al setInterval?

Comment: Yo suelo usarlo, lo que debes hacer es darle un uso debido. en tu caso cada 2 minutos se ejecuta no creo que halla problemas. lo que no se es para que quieres que inicie detectando novedades. Se supone que acaba de ejecutarse para que en los próximos 2 minutos se ejecute y así poder estar detectando los fallos.

Comment: No te va a crear un loop ya que la función se ejecuta la primera vez fuera del contexto setInteraval. Referente a si está bien, si es correcto. Cualquier duda me dices.

Answer (score 1):

No te va a crear un loop ya que la función se ejecuta la primera vez fuera del contexto setInteraval. Referente a si está bien, si es correcto.
Cualquier duda me dices.